# Why energy conservation implied $\partial_{z} T_{z\bar z}=-\partial_{\bar z} T_{zz}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The conformal in variance in 2d CFT required $T_{z\bar z}=0$ (the vanishing of the trace $T_a^a=0$) and the conservation equation were $\partial_{\bar z} T_{zz}=\partial_{ z} T_{\bar z\bar z}=0$, which was translated from $\partial_a T^{ab}=0$ in the $(\sigma,\tau)$ coordinate, as shown in the [Tong's string lecture notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) page 66.

However, in order to prove the anomaly term, the page 87 introduced an energy conservation equation $\partial_{z} T_{z\bar z}=-\partial_{\bar z} T_{zz}$, but without mention where it came from. Notice that from page 65 and page 66 the conservation equation $\nabla^\alpha T_{\alpha\beta}=0$ translated into $\partial_{\bar z} T_{zz}=\partial_{z} T_{\bar z \bar z}=0$ different from the "energy conservation equation".

Why energy conservation implied $\partial_{z} T_{z\bar z}=-\partial_{\bar z} T_{zz}$ (in the quantum case)?

Comment: That's the just the ordinary EM-conservation expression written in conformal coordinates. Or are you asking why the conservation is non-anomalous?

Comment: @NiharKarve Both. The conservation of the noether current associated with the space time translation was $\nabla^\alpha T_{\alpha \beta}=0$ and was different as explained above. What did you mean by EM-conservation? (This is string, it's not like a U(1) charge always exists.) I also wasn't sure why this conservation is non-anomalous.

Comment: EM here = energy-momentum conservation. $\nabla^\alpha T_{\alpha\beta}=0$ implies (1) $\partial_{z} T_{z\bar z}+\partial_{\bar z} T_{zz}=0$ and (2) $\partial_{\bar z} T_{\bar z z}+\partial_{z} T_{\bar z\bar z}=0$, just write it out. Your page 65/66 identity also happens to incorporate conformal invariance ($T_{z\bar z}=0$ in conformal coords) to kill the first terms in (1) and (2). But (1) and (2) are the general expressions.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why we're certain there's no anomaly in the conservation. However I think it has something do with the fact that during quantization, you can either make $T$ traceless *or* make it conserved - but not both unless the central charge is 0 [Blumenhagen Ch.4].